# php remove url but keep anchor

Tags: php, url, replace

I have some links in a long text:

```
<a class="class1" href="https://www.test.com/de/de/products/2018/street/bike/details.html#2"><sup>2</sup></a>
```

and I like to remove the href but keep the anchor like this:

```
<a class="class1" href="#2"><sup>2</sup></a>
```

The URL is not always the same, so this part "de/de/products/2018/street/bike/" varies. And the number of the anchors varies, too.

Is this possible?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: It is ideal to always post a question and show what you have tried or at least what you have googled. You can use codepen, jsfiddle, etc

Comment: If you can´t use `jquery` try with [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

Answer (score 0):

Ok this was really simple at the end.

Because I can delete all hrefs in the code I used

```
$dateninhalt = preg_replace('/http[\s\S]+?.html/', '', $dateninhalt);
```

So from the links

```
<a class="class1" href="https://www.test.com/de/de/products/2018/street/bike/details.html#2"><sup>2</sup></a>
```

everything from "http" to ".html", including the both strings, is replaced by nothing ('').

Answer (score -1):

Check my pen [here](https://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/gmyoWM). I define the value of the href based on input selection using jquery.

You will use the attr method:

```
$('a#attibute').attr("href", "the url comes here");
```

Hope it works

Comment: worth noting OP wanted php solution - jquery may not be available on their site

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer! Unfortunately I need to use php. With jQuery it would be easy but this str_replace thing kills me.